# blazor telerik virtualization of remote data for grid

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, blazor

I'm using TelerikGrid in blazor and I wanted this feature to request for a part of data and when client scrolled down to that part of data then make another request to get the second part of data but I couldn't make it so anyone knows how this can be done with telerik UI for blazor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a lot of research and found out in order to make this you can use `OnRead` event of grid with `ScrollMode="@GridScrollMode.Virtual"` 
but also you must give your total count and page size to your grid

```
<TelerikGrid Data=@GridData TotalCount="@Total"
             FilterMode="@GridFilterMode.FilterMenu"
             ScrollMode="@GridScrollMode.Virtual"
             Height="400px" 
             RowHeight="50"
             PageSize="20"
             OnRead="@ReadItems">
```

on read event return `GridReadEventArgs` which contains `Skip` and `PageSize`

so you can use them to make a request and get that part of data

Comment: You can also find useful the docs on custom operations https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/components/grid/manual-operations